# Umbraco - working with document types

Tags: umbraco

I've started working with Umbraco yesterday and my vision of working with it was as follows:

- add document types
- create a basic content tree
- create templates
- edit document types & templates adding what I need and replacing "lorem ipsum" with the content from Umbraco

The problem is that I added two properties to a Client document type. Then I got this while trying to edit content:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This is hard to understand for me, because:

- Umbraco is supposed to be friendly ('the friendliest...')
- Database structure is organized in a way that this should not be the problem
- Even using Fluent NHibernate Migrator adding a field to a database just creates another field without throwing any exceptions - and here?

So what's the idea here? Document types are once and for all and you can't edit them?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be helpful to know which version of Umbraco you are using as there are minor differences in the versions 4.x and now with v5 it's a completely different game with a complete new codebase on ASP.NET MVC.

In some versions of v4 there had been a bug where you get the error message you posted when you have added two document types with the same alias or two properties with the same alias to one document type.

So that you cannot edit the content is not the intention of umbraco ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm currently using 4.7.1.1. It's good to know that my idea of working with umbraco is not fundamentally flowed. I might have two properties/documents with the same alias  I'll check on that.

Comment: You're welcome, another good resource is the forum of umbraco itself: http://our.umbraco.org/forum